# Setting HttpOnly Cookies in .NET 3.1 Back-End

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, .net-core

I'm working on a project whose back-end is built in .NET 3.1 and Angular 11 for the front-end. I'm trying to set the HttpOnly attribute on true for cookies via the Startup method, which is extended by various APIs and Managers through the entire application: so far the current configuration is as follows.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          ...

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>{

            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            
        });

       ...

     }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      ...

      app.UseCookiePolicy();

      ...

    }
```

Anyways, when checking via the Network tab in Chrome/Firefox the HttpOnly flag is not set, what am I missing?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to pass in the cookie policy options you created.
Using this line
 `services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options ...`

makes the cookie policy available later on but doesn't configure it in your startup.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cookie-policy-middleware-1 you'll need to create a cookie policy and then pass that in to
`app.UseCookiePolicy();`

Otherwise, it uses the default cookie policy which doesn't have them set to what you would prefer.